# Prevent WooCommerce from removing my custom nav wrapper?

Tags: woocommerce

I've made a custom nav menu wrapper for WooCommerce using wp_nav_menu's items_wrap parameter to add "Check out( [amount] )" around a menu item. But whenever I add a product to the cart from the shop page WooCommerce updates the menu item, removing my wrapper. How can I prevent WooCommerce from doing that (add my wrapper somewhere that makes WooCommerce behave the way I want it to)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up removing the »cart_totals« class from the link itself, and added a span with the class instead. WooCommerce updates the span instead of the anchor itself – so let's just hope WC don't change their selector at some point in the future, Yak!